# pandas: make a DataFrame from a combination of two dimensional and one dimensional arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I often need to call groupby().apply(). Since the callback function of apply() is only allowed to return a Series or DataFrame (or maybe a scalar), it becomes rather awkward if my call back function needs to return a tuple of one dimensional and two dimensional arrays, since I will have to pack them into a DataFrame and then unpack to the arrays once I get the results from apply().

Example:

```
def my_callback(g):
"""This function takes the group g and calculates a two dim array and a 
one dim array"""
  a = np.ones(len(g),2)
  b = np.ones(len(g))
  #I need to return a and b 
  return a, b #this won't work

x = data.groupby('key').apply(my_callback)
```

Does anyone have some suggestions? If pandas allow more flexible return value from the callback, it will be much more convenient.

Now to see a few use cases, here are a few examples:
Case 1: I need to transform the DataFrame to the independent and dependent variables of a regression. The transformation involves generating a 2D array and a 1D array group by group and then stack together the rows of the arrays from each group. It would be great if only I can write:

```
X, Y = data.groupby('key').apply(my_callback)
```

Using a DataFrame sort of works but it involves np.column_stack().

Case 2: I want to transform the DataFrame to two arrays of different rows and columns group by group. I don't think there is any way to do this today, unless we encode everything as a 1D series.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why can't you just combine the results and unpack afterwards?

Comment: I would argue that it's *more* awkward that you want to return a `tuple` from a `groupby` operation.

Comment: I am trying to transform the data points in a DataFrame to a two dimensional array group by group and then transform the same data to a different one dimensional array. For example, the two dimensional array can be the independent variables of a regression while the one dimensional array can be the dependent variable. I could have written two functions, one for each array, and apply them separately, but that would be very slow. So traverse the data once and generate both arrays would be preferred.

Comment: Now as for why packing the result into a dataframe is awkward, not to mention it is slow. The two dim array is the result of np.dot(). So when I need to construct the DataFrame as the return value, I have one two dim array and one one dim array at hand. I can then either use np.column_stack to stack them together or write a loop to slice the two dim array one column at a time to a dict. Neither is not ideal.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question. The other question wants to return two scalars. I found that use case on the pandas github. I am here to return two arrays of different dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use apply here, and unless you are using a cythonized function which  can operate on a frame/series, it doesn't make any difference in perf.

Iterate on the groupby itself, creating a list of 'stuff' (in this case a tuple returned by the callback function). Then you can further process. You can return anything here (including the grouped dataframe if you wish)

```
[26]: df = DataFrame([['foo',1],['foo',2],['bar',3],['bar',4]],columns=list('AB'))

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
     A  B
0  foo  1
1  foo  2
2  bar  3
3  bar  4

In [35]: def f(g, grp):
   ....:     return (g, len(grp), grp['B'].sum())
   ....: 

In [36]: print [ f(g, grp) for g, grp in df.groupby('A') ]
[('bar', 2, 7), ('foo', 2, 3)]
```